# Como hacer referencia a si mismo con un botón en python tkinter

Tags: python, array, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un vector de botones.

```
interfaceLectorNotas = Toplevel()
interfaceLectorNotas.title("Enciclopedia")
interfaceLectorNotas.geometry("800x600")
lienzo = Canvas(interfaceLectorNotas, width=800, height=600)
lienzo.place(x=0, y=0)
btnsText = ["#", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M","N", "Ñ", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
btns = []
contador = 0

for i in btnsText:
    btns.append(Button(lienzo, text=i, command=lambda : print("Akas")))
    btns[contador].place(x=(22*contador)+4, y=2)
    contador = contador + 1
```

Necesito saber como hacer referencia a si mismo... osea si yo presiono el boton A que me imprima A??? como puedo hacerlo????

Comment: No tienes ninguna función en el código llamada `lambda` que sea llamada al presionar el botón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observa el siguiente ejemplo:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

btnsText = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in btnsText:
    btn = Button(root, text=i, command=lambda:print(i))
    btn.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

En este ejemplo, al hacer click en cualquier botón se imprimirá *"D"*, ya que al finalizar el *bucle for*, `i == "D"` (el último elemento de la lista). Sin embargo el texto de cada botón si es el esperado (`"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` y `"D"` respectivamente), independientemente del valor final de `i`, ya que **el texto del botón no es un valor por referencia**, sino una copia del *valor actual* de `i`.

En vez de utilizar `command` puedes manejar el evento `'<Button-1>'`. Por ejemplo:

```py
from tkinter import *


def show_me(e):
    print(e.widget.cget('text'))


root = Tk()

btnsText = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in btnsText:
    btn = Button(root, text=i)
    btn.bind('<Button-1>', show_me)
    btn.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

El evento `'<Button-1>'` se dispara cuando se hace *click izquierdo* con el ratón. El manejador del evento es la función `show_me`, que debe recibir un argumento que hace referencia al propio evento (`e`).

Dentro del manejador `show_me` puedes acceder al *widget* sobre el que se ha disparado el evento mediante `e.widget`, y como asignaste el texto que quieres mostrar al propio texto del botón, puedes imprimirlo mediante `e.widget.cget('text')`.

**NOTA:** Si intentas utilizar `btn = Button(root, text=i, command=lambda:print(btn.cget('text')))` no funcionará, ya que al finalizar el *bucle for*, la variable `btn` hace referencia al último botón (siempre se imprimiría *"D"*).

Puedes utilizar *funciones lambda* si lo prefieres:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

btnsText = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in btnsText:
    btn = Button(root, text=i)
    btn.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: print(e.widget.cget('text')))
    btn.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias amigo programador, funcionó de maravilla.

Comment: Me alegro de haber sido útil jeje. Un saludo! ^^